# Help with regex to match any url but that of admin folder

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am stuck with something I know must be simple but been going round in circles for a while now.

I want to create a regular expression for use with a cms routing feature using php and preg_match that matches any URL that doesn't begin with the string 'admin/' as somedomain.com/admin/ will be the admin part of the cms.

I have tried so far

```
preg_match('#^([^admin])+(.+)$#', 'mens-books'))
```

which fails as the url string 'mens-books' I am looking for is a match against the letter m in the string 'admin' so it fails.

I have tried doing it like this also:

```
preg_match('#^([^admin$])+(.+)$#', 'mens-books'))
```

as a dollar symbolises the end of string but that didn't work either.

I then did this:

```
preg_match('#^[?!=admin]+(.+)$#', 'mens-books'))
```

which returned true but only I think because the ?!= in the regex now will match anything that is beginning with a, d, m, i or n.

Is anyone able to help with this please. I am open to any suggestions.

Thankyou.

Matt

Answer (score 6):

```
if (substr($url, 0, 6) !== 'admin/')
{
  echo 'Yippie';
}
```

But to answer the regex question. When you use square brackets, you're specifying a character class. That means `[admin]` matches a single character that is either an `a`, a `d` an `m` an `i` or an `n`. If you skip the brackets, you're matching a literal string. But, as my code proofs, it is not needed to use regex at all if you need to check if a string starts with a fixed substring.

Comment: Eh, yeah probably. :D Fixed it.

Comment: @GolezTrol, actually there is a very simple regex way to do this. See my answer. But for the OP's actual use case, your method is better (I even upvoted it).

Comment: Yes, there are multiple ways to do this in regex too, and it's not always bad to to so. But I sometimes feel people tend to reach for regex too soon without considering alternatives. RegExes are actually quite complex. Not only to write but also to process. One might think that it is an easy command because it's just a single line, while in fact even the simplest regex needs a complex parser. Using substr is just copying and comparing bytes. You can writes tens or hundreds of lines of code that may still outperform a single regex statement. :)

Comment: While that's true, the difference in efficiency is irrelevant in almost all contexts (it only matters if the code gets called in an extremely high throughput method, or thousands of times in a row). For most cases, I usually just go for whatever is clearest to read. In this case, the regex is more convoluted than a simple substring check. But in some cases, I will opt for a regex for clarity over some other method.

Comment: Thanks, I could do this but I am building he site within codeigniter framework and dont want to edit the core files which would add extra problems when upgrading to newer versions etc. I there only want to edit the routes.php file in my codeigniter app. My question is here too in the ci forum if you have time [link](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/191136/)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use regular expressions, what you are looking for is something called [negative lookahead](http://www.google.com/search?q=regex%20negative%20lookahead), which is a zero-width assertion (it checks for the existence or lack of text without 'eating' it). It would work something like this:

```
^(?!admin\/)
```

Here are some specific preg_match examples:

```
preg_match('/^(?!admin\/)/', 'mens-books');        // true
preg_match('/^(?!admin\/)/', 'admin/mens-books');  // false
preg_match('/^(?!admin\/)/', 'admin-mens-books');  // true
```

Comment: Hi Ben, Thanks, can u provide a working example of this though in a preg_match similar to the ones I provided above please. I have tried this but am still stuck I think. Thanks.

Comment: @Matthew, I've updated my answer with some specific examples.

Answer (score 2):

the brackets [] are used for any single character [admin] is a, d, m, i, or n not admin, what you probably want is (admin).  So anything that begins with admin would be /^(admin).*$/ then the easiest way is to put a not in your code.

example (not a php coder so sorry in advance):

```
$pattern = '/^(admin)\/.*$/'
if (preg_match($pattern, $url) == 1) {
    $match = true;
} else {
    $match = false;
}
```

that is assuming your trying to get back a boolean

Comment: Hi DrPppr242 Thanks, can u provide a working example of this though in a preg_match similar to the ones I provided above please. I have tried this but am still stuck I think. Thanks

Comment: This might be easier if you could provide a bit more context, it would be easier to help you out.  If this is a part of a larger function can you include the rest of the logic in the example?

Answer (score 0):

Try `^(?!admin/).*$` but I think comparing a substring is much faster.

Comment: That will fail to match anything shorter than six characters.  Also, you need to replace the `$` with `^`.

Comment: Thanks Hakre, are you able to provide a working example of this in a preg_match function similar to my code above please though, I have read loads on building regular expression but they all then break when i put them inside a preg_match

Answer (score 0):

Im not entirely sure I follow but dont you just want

```
preg_match('^(/)?admin(/)?.*', 'mens-books'))
```

eg starts either with /admin or admin

Comment: Hi BugFinder, I have tried this but get the following warning: Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending delimiter '^' found in C:\wamp\www\regex-test.php on line 28 and also it still fails sorry, are you able to test this for me please?

Comment: Sadly I cant completely test it as my php isnt liking the preg functions. I realised my mistake is omitting the search tags, it should read something more like preg_match('/^(/\)?admin(\/)?.*/', 'mens-books')) but, I cant do a lot to verify without a working preg set of commands.. and from here, cant recompile php

Comment: The regex needs non-alphanumeric delimiters; e.g. `'#^(/)?admin(/)?.*#'`.  See http://php.net/regexp.reference.delimiters for more information.

Comment: preg_match('/^(\/)?admin(\/)?.*/', $string) worked according to my friend