# Codeigniter route regex - match any string except 'admin'

Tags: regex, codeigniter, routes

I'd like to send any route that doesn't match an admin route, to my "event" controller. This seems to be a fairly common requirement and a cursory search throws up all sorts of [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285677/help-with-regex-to-match-any-url-but-that-of-admin-folder) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285677/help-with-regex-to-match-any-url-but-that-of-admin-folder).

The solution, as I understand, seems to be using a negative lookahead in the regex. So my attempt looks like this:

```
$route['(?!admin).*'] = "event";
```

..which works. Well, sort of. It does send any non-admin request to my "event" controller, but I need it to pass the actual string that was matched: so **/my-new-event/** is routed to **/event/my-new-event/**

I tried:

```
$route['(?!admin).*'] = "event/$0";
$route['(?!admin).*'] = "event/$1";
$route['(?!admin)(.*)'] = "event/$0";
$route['(?!admin)(.*)'] = "event/$1";
```

... and a few other increasingly random and desperate permutations. All result in a 404 page.

What's the correct syntax for passing the matched string to the controller?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think you can do "negative routing".

But as routes do have an order : "routes will run in the order they are defined. Higher routes will always take precedence over lower ones." I would do my admin one first then anything else.

If I suppose your admin path is looking like "/admin/..." I would suggest :

```
$route['admin/(:any)'] = "admincontroller/$1";
$route['(:any)'] = "event/$1";
```

Comment: That does indeed work, thanks. Strange that negative matching won't pass the matched string, but this functions well as a workaround.